# How to style select box form. Does it have any limitations?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying style select box form in HTML/CSS. I need something like this:

[image]

My current result is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LPN4J/1/

Is it possible?

Here is my code:

**html:**

```
<label>
    <select>
        <option selected> Select your option </option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
</label>​
```

**css:**

```
body, html {background:#444; text-align:center; padding:50px 0;}

select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    select {padding-right:18px}
}

label {position:relative}
label:after {
    content:'<>';
    font:11px "Consolas", monospace;
    color:#aaa;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    right:8px; top:2px;
    padding:0 0 2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    right:6px; top:0px;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    display:block;
}
```

Please any hint. I learn css from scratch.

Comment: You need to use JS/jQuery

Comment: This has been covered all over SO, but again: these elements cannot be completely controlled as they are dependent on the operating system for their style. You will have to use Javascript to change this. Google is your best friend!

Comment: want something like this? http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: @iKishore for?? my comment? is that se wants?

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui: Good alternative, thanks

Comment: Possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui better than spoon-feeding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, according to your question [this plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for bootstrap may help you.

**Usage:**

1. Download [this](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/zipball/master)(.zip) or [this](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/tarball/master)(.tar.gz) to download the plugin
2. Then put the files in your related folder, respectively.
3. On your select box, just add a class of `selectpicker`.

Comment: How to use this twitter bootstrap plugin only for one element on the page? If I use it all my site use twitter bootstrap element (url are blue etc)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

html:

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select>
      <option>Here is the first option</option>
      <option>The second option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

css:

```
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 268px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   }

.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(http://cdn.bavotasan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/down_arrow_select.jpg) no-repeat right #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LPN4J/3/)